# OmniPersistence: usage of VersionedEntity is producing OptimisticLockException

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, optimistic-locking

I am experimenting with the library [OmniPersistence](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnipersistence).

I have a problem using the class `org.omnifaces.persistence.model.VersionedEntity`. In my code there is a simple entity class *City*.

```
@Entity
public class City extends VersionedEntity<Long> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String postalCode;
    private String name;

    ... (getter + setter)
}
```

There is a REST-Service that exposes the Entity for some client-applications. But every time I want to update an object a `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException` is thrown. The problem is that the version attribute is always `null`. A look in the [code of `VersionedEntity`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnipersistence/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/persistence/model/VersionedEntity.java) revealed that there is no setter method, but a comment

> // No setter! JPA takes care of this.

I do understand the intention of the absence of the setter method but that is the reason for the exception.

### Question

Is my architecture so poor (exposing the entity class in a web-service) or is it maybe reasonable to add a setter method although JPA should handle the value/manipulation of the `@Version`ed attribute?

---

**Edit** (as requested by the comment)

My update method is basically the one in OmniPersistence' [`BaseEntityService`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnipersistence/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/persistence/service/BaseEntityService.java#L994). My service class looks like the following.

```
@Stateless
public class CityService extends BaseEntityService<Long, City> {
    public Long count() {
        return super.createLongQuery("select count(c) from City c").getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

My controller is the REST endpoint.

```
@Path("city")
public class CityEndpoint {
    @Inject
    private CityService cityService;

    @GET @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAll() {
        List<City> cities = cityService.list();
        return Response.ok(cities).build();
    }

    @GET @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("{id}")
    public Response get(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        return Response.ok(cityService.getById(id)).build();
    }

    @POST @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response create(City city) {
        cityService.persist(city);
        return Response.created(URI.create(String.format("city/%s", Objects.toString(city.getId())))).build();
    }

    @POST @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("update")
    public Response update(City city) {
        System.out.println(city);
        City updated = cityService.update(city);
        return Response.ok(updated).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("count")
    public Response count() {
        return Response.ok(cityService.count()).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your update method and maybe also your controller

Comment: thank you for adding. The problem here is, as you already mentioned, the null in version. It is a good practise to use DTO for the client (frontend) and hide unnecessary informations. You should load your city byId or something else, set the new updated values und save it. Its also kind of a security issue to have entities directly in the frontend because user could change some attributes they may cannot change in the current view. Without some checks you will also put this manipulated stuff in your DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JPA specification document](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) provides an important hint that you **must not** manipulate the `@Version` attribute, see section 3.4.2, on page 90

> An entity may access the state of its version field or property or
> export a method for use by the application to access the version,
> but must not modify the version value.

and

> The version attribute is updated **by the persistence provider** runtime
> when the object is written to the database.

So the comment (”No setter! JPA takes care of this.“) you find in `VersionedEntity` is absolutely reasonable. In essence, you should not change (or `null`) the `@Version` attribute from higher application levels.

In your case, it seems, you must compensate the ”lost“ (=nulled) *version* effect, eg by introducing a DTO for `City`. Otherwise, you will always run into an `OptimisticLockException`.

Comment: OK, **must not modify** is pretty explicit, I did not know that, thanks for the information @MWiesner. 
I still have a problem thinking this through. Because that`s to complicated to discus it in the comments, I created another question [Does JPA @Version feature play well with DTOs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73191718/4903755). @MWiesner I would by grateful if you have a look at it ;-)